# Delete path up to certain name in batch that lists files and their path

Tags: list, file, batch-file, split, path

```
@echo off
del 0List.txt 2 > nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\MyFolder\Ready\*.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do echo %%~fI>>0List.txt
```

Using this code, I list TXT files in a folder (Ready) with its subfolders. It creates the txt with the list of files. Only, I want to finally get rid of the D;\ up to Ready. So

```
D:\MyFolder\Ready\file1.txt 
D:\MyFolder\Ready\file2.txt
D:\MyFolder\Ready\My Sub Folder\file434.txt
```

should just be trimmed in the list I create to

```
Ready\file1.txt 
Ready\file2.txt
Ready\My Sub Folder\file434.txt
```

I looked at some questions but couldn't impelement it in to the above code, Would appreciate  if someone can show me where to add to remove the first part of the path.

Comment: Mmm... You want not to _"get rid of the D;\ up to Ready"_, but up to MyFolder\. Isn't it? Or get rid of the D;\ up to Ready and then insert Ready at beginning

Comment: Change `"delims="` to `"tokens=2,* delims=\"` and `%%~fI`, _(which could have just been `%%I`)_, to `%%H`.

Comment: @Aacini It would be more flexible if no matter the path to 'Ready' it cleared everything before 'Ready'. so Ready\files.txt should stay and Ready/Subfolder/files.txt should stay.

Comment: @Compo No that doesn't work I did put for /F "tokens=2,* delims=\" %%l and then in the echo I added:  do echo %%H but that outputs %%H or with fI it output the folder Ready itself not any files after

Comment: My mistake @programc7r, that's because I always use `%%G In`, as you were using `%%I in`, you'll use `%%J` instead of `%%H`.

Comment: Yes now it works,  thanks, added a line with the complete code for it on my first post.

Comment: I have removed that revision, as answers do not belong in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this, which just keeps the last leaf of `%BaseDirectory%`:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "BaseDirectory=D:\MyFolder\Ready"
Set "SearchMask=*.txt"

(For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('PushD "%BaseDirectory%\.." 2^>NUL ^&^& (CD ^& PopD^)') Do For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%H In ('Dir "%BaseDirectory%\%SearchMask%" /A:-D /B /S 2^>NUL') Do Set "FullPath=%%H" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%I In ("!FullPath:*%%~G\=!") Do EndLocal & Echo %%~I) 1>"%~dp00List.txt"

Pause

EndLocal
```

Comment: What you  corrected in the code yesterday already worked. But I did update with your code directly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. This will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "cutstring=\ready\"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /S "%sourcedir%\MyFolder\Ready\*.txt" 2^>nul') do (
 echo %%~fI
 SET "name=%%~fI"
 ECHO %cutstring:~1%!name:*%cutstring%=!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Before we start, notice the line `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`.

This line establishes a "local environment" which means that any changes to the environment are discarded when the script ends (or an `ENDLOCAL` statement is executed). The effect is that running the environment does not become "polluted" by changes made by other jobs in the same session.

It is therefore standard practice to include a `setlocal` command at the start of a batch file, immediately after an `@echo off`

The `enabledelayedexpansion` is optional but is the only way to switch on the `delayedexpansion` syntax, where `!var!` is the **current** value of a variable, as it may be changed in a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of statements). See [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) for documentation.

Your `del 0List.txt 2 > nul` does not do what you appear to aim at doing. It deletes files `0List.txt` & `2` You need the `2` directly before the `>` to redirect error messages to the bit-bin.

Batch substringing can only be conducted on ordinary variables, not `metavariables` like `%%I` or `%1`, so it's necessary to assign it to a standard variable before it can be manipulated.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces on the source line are NOT included in the value assigned.

Then `echo` the value of `cutstring` from the *second* character (note that character numbering in batch starts at "character #0" concatenated with the *current* contents of `name` (as `name` will change on each loop) - except the string up to the contents of `cutstring`. See `set /?` from the prompt for documentation - or thousands of examples on SO.

I've left the output being display on the console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested improvements I had this working yesterday and used also the code suggested below but this is still useful info